# the global section of any affine open subset of a Noetherian scheme is Noetherian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am trying to follow the proof of proposition 3.46 of Qing Liu's algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves. Suppose that $(X, O_{X})$ is a Noetherian scheme (can be covered by finite affine open sets whose global section is a Noetherian ring) and we want to show that for any open affine $U$, $O_{X}(U)$ is Noetherian. It is easy to check that $U$ is also Noetherian so we can cover $U$ by finitely many affine open $U_i$ such that $O_{X}(U_i)$ is Noetherian. Let $I$ be an ideal of $O_{X}(U)$. As $IO_{X}(U_i)$ is finitely generated, there exists a finitely generated ideal $J \subset I$ such that $IO_{X}(U_i) = JO_{X}(U_i)$.

I do not quite follow this last sentence above. First of all, how is $IO_{X}(U_i)$ defined? My guess is whenever you take the product you first restrict $I$ to $O_{X}(U_i)$ using the restriction map from the definition of a sheaf. If this is true, why is it true that $IO_{X}(U_i)$ is finitely generated and it suffices to use a finitely generated ideal inside $I$?

Comment: This seems rather confused - there are several things missing (your definition of a noetherian scheme, the explanation for the second sentence, etc). Is this a proof that you're trying to write on your own, or are you attempting to understand something someone else wrote? If the latter, where is this from?

Comment: My apology and I have updated the question @KReiser

Answer (score 2):

$I\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ is defined to be the ideal generated by the image of $I$ under the restriction map $\mathcal{O}_X(U)\to\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$. This is finitely generated because $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ is noetherian.

To see that we can now find a finite generating set of $I$ from this information, for each $i$ some finite number of elements of $I$ must have images which generate $I\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ by noetherianity. Since there are finitely many $U_i$, this gives us a finite list of elements of $I$. I claim that these elements generate $I$: the map $\mathcal{O}_X(U)^N\to I$ specified by the generators we chose is surjective after localizing at any prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ (since the localization at a prime in $U_i$ can be computed starting from $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$) and a map of modules which is surjective at every prime is surjective.

Comment: Just to make sure I fully understand your last sentence: we can further form a map $O_{X}(U)^{N} \to IO_{X}(U_i)$ for each $i$. Now we want to use the universal property of the localization to get a map from the localization of the LHS to the RHS, but I am not sure why this is doable(where are we using the fact that $U$ is affine?).

Comment: No, that's not quite right. Really what's happening here is we're defining a map of sheaves $\mathcal{O}_U^N \to \widetilde{I}$ globally and then checking that it's surjective locally (ie on stalks) which implies that the map on global sections is surjective (there's at least two places where $U$ affine is really important there). The map $\mathcal{O}_X(U)^N\to I$ becomes the map $\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)^N\to I\mathcal{O}_X(U_i)$ after restriction, then we localize to get the map on stalks (again, $U$ and $U_i$ affine is key to get the map on stalks by localization here).